# how to change user and group of a file inside the docker in gitlab-ci

Tags: linux, gitlab, chown, logrotate

I have a file which when I mount it to the docker, the user and group will change.

```
root@b2d3cb9b2aab:/# ls -lh /etc/logrotate.d/
total 36K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  120 Sep 11  2021 alternatives
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  173 Feb 22 19:00 apt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  130 Oct 14  2019 btmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  112 Sep 11  2021 dpkg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  128 May  4  2021 exim4-base
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  108 May  4  2021 exim4-paniclog
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root 4.0K Jun 14 18:56 home
-rw-r--r-- 1 99005 1000  876 Jun 14 18:40 syslog-ng     <<<<<<<<<<<<< this file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  145 Oct 14  2019 wtmp
```

I am using gitlab-ci to run my docker as below :

```
docker container run -d --restart=always \
        --name my-syslogger -p 5514:514/udp -p 601:601 \
        -v /data/my-logs:/var/log \
        -v $PWD/syslogger/syslog-ng.conf:/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf \
        -v $PWD/syslogger/syslog-ng:/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng \
        /balabit/syslog-ng
```

Then I tried to remove the "-v $PWD/syslogger/syslog-ng:/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng "

then copy the file manually by using docker cp, but again the same result.

```
docker cp $PWD/syslogger/syslog-ng  my-syslogger:/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
```

Then I want to change the owner and group by the below command, it is working if I run them separately but I am afraid it works with gitlab-ci.

```
docker exec -it --user root my-syslogger /bin/bash && chown -R root:root /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
```

would you mind advising me on the best approach to change this file owner to root?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it as below:

```
docker exec -it -d --user root my-syslogger /bin/chown -R root:root /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
```